# Как прервать отладку без выполнения дальнейшего кода в Intellij Idea?

Tags: java, intellij-idea

В Intellij Idea Ultimate запускаю такой код в режиме отладки:

```
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("Это не должно отображаться");
    }
}
```

Брейкпойнт ставлю на строку `System.out.println("Это не должно отображаться");`. После запуска в debug режиме выполнение останавливается на строке с брейкпойнтом. Если сейчас нажать кнопку Stop в IDE (т.е. прервать отладку), то в консоли появится строка "Это не должно отображаться". Разве при нажатии Stop не должно прерваться дальнейшее выполнение?
Проблема наблюдается в версии 2017.3.5 и 2019.2.2 (актуальная на данный момент).

Comment: это скорее не баг, а фича идеи.

Comment: @Tsyklop оказывается, в настройках (File -> Settings -> Build, Execution, Deployment -> Debugger) нужно поставить флажок для опции 'Kill the debug process immediately'.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Ответ из саппорта:**
Пожалуйста, включите опцию "Kill the debug process immediately" в меню `Preferences | Build, Execution, Deployment | Debugger` чтобы избежать такого поведения:
[https://i.stack.imgur.com/c7CAM.png

Однако имейте ввиду, что мягкая остановка (при выключенной опции `kill the debug process immediately`) позволяет очищать используемые программой ресурсы (удалить временные файлы, закрыть подключения к базе данных и дескрипторы файлов, сбросить кэши). Именно поэтому опция жесткой остановки выключена по-умолчанию.

Подробное обсуждение данной проблемы ведется в нашем YouTrack:

[https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-164593][2]

Там, в частности, Вы сможете найти то как работает опция `Kill the debug process immediately` в особых случаях (таких как закрытие IDEA, нажатие кнопки перезапуска программы итд).